# How to optimize an algorithm for solving differential equation?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, numpy, loops

I'm solving a differential equation by using an algorithm but my implementation in Python is very slow and I wonder why. The algorithm works as follows

1. Set up initial condition (an initial function `u0`)
2. Calculate `u1` by using a quadrature routine (I'm using scipy integrate) that integrates over u0 with some modifications (shifting the function and muliplying its parameters with some basic functions)
3. Go on to calculate `u2` and so on, with the same procedure as `u1` but depending on `u1` instead of `u0` (and so on)

This should give me a function that calculates for some `x` the value of the solution at every time point 1, 2, ..., N, for some N. You find explanations to the single steps in commented in the program. If anything is unclear I'm glad to explain it. (Question is below)

```
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy import interpolate, integrate, stats

# Some values that determine the Differential Equation
y = 0.024
o = 0.115
p = 0.35

#Defining the initial value, i.e. the function we start with
def u0(x):
    return stats.beta.pdf(x, 2.7, 3.05)

#Determining the spatial and time grid on which I'd like the function to show me results
L = 1
N = 1000

dx = L / N
x = np.arange(0, L, dx)

t = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
dt = 0.001


#Simulating the Brownian motion on which the Differential equation depends
cov = np.zeros((len(t), len(t)))
B_i = np.zeros((len(t), len(t)))

for i in range(len(t)):
    for j in range(i + 1):
        B_i[i, j] = np.sqrt(dt)

mean = np.zeros_like(t)
B = np.dot(B_i, np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, np.identity(len(t))))
B = np.concatenate(([0], B), axis=-1)


#This is a shift operator that is used for the solution, it is part of the analytical solution and shifts the inserted parameter by another parameter a
def shift(func, a):
    def shift(x):
        return func(x - a)
    return shift

#This is a scale operator that is used for the solution, it is part of the analytical solution and multiplies the function by some parameter
def scale(func, a=1):
    return a*func

#This truncates a function (I only need results in the area of 0<x<1)
def trunc(func):
    def trunc(x):
        if x <= 0:
            return 0
        elif x >= 1:
            return 0
        else:
            return func(x)
    return trunc

#This is the quadrature routine
def quad(func, a, b):
    return integrate.quad(func, a, b)

#Interpolation on the grid
def myinterpolate(func):
    x = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
    y = func(x[:])
    return interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind = 'cubic', fill_value="extrapolate")

#Modification function such that the Differential equation can be solved for the next time step
def gauss(func, t):
    def gauss(x):
        def pregau(z):
            arg = x + t ** (1 / 2) * z
            return func(arg) * math.exp(-(z**2)/2)

        integration = integrate.quad(pregau, -np.inf, np.inf)[0]
        return (2 * math.pi) ** (-1/2) * integration

    return gauss

#Function that is used in each time step to calculate the solution for the new time step
def f_temp(ui, B):
    def f_temp(x):
        arg = o * np.sqrt(1 - p ** (2)) * dt
        increment = o * p * B + y * dt
        return shift(gauss(ui, arg), increment)(x)

    return np.vectorize(f_temp)


#This is the function that gives me (for inital value u0) the solution at every time step for a specific x that I feed it
def vundl(x, u=u0):
    v = [myinterpolate(u)]
    vx = [myinterpolate(u)(x)[()]]

    #In my case  1000, but it takes a lot of time to get to even go to i=100
    for i in range(1, 1000):

        vi = trunc(myinterpolate(f_temp(v[i-1], B[i] - B[i-1]))) 
        vxi = vi(x)
        v.append(vi)
        vx.append(vxi)

    return list(map(lambda x: x[()], vx)) 

print(vundl(0.01, u0))
```

As you can see, I already put `f_temp` out of the loop, which made it a lot quicker. Before I was only able to calculate until i = 10, as it took too long, afterwards I was able to calculate until i=100.  Is there a way of making this program quicker? I'm not very experienced in programming or Python in particular and it took me lots of work to make this work at leat a bit. I'm grateful for any advice.

Comment: The way you use `np.vectorize` seems inefficient here. I advise you to redesign the code as a bunch of nested loops and then use numpy vectorization *without* `np.vectorize`. `np.vectorize` does not vectorize your code efficiently: it run a Python function for each element and this is the root of the problem: CPython function are painfully slow because it is an interpreter and Numpy cannot optimize them.

Comment: How do I reorganize this as nested loops?

Comment: I'm sorry, for the inspecific question. As you can see, I used the ```np.vectorize``` for the ```myinterpolate``` function. I tried rephrasing the myinterpolate function with a loop, this didn't provide for a faster result. Did I miss something, where to put the loops?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do those redefinitions of nested functions do? I've never seen such a thing.

Comment: @Lith what exactly are you talking about?

Comment: @Leoncino I mean, for example, `def shift(func,a)` followed by `def shift(x)`. But it doesn't matter, I guess it has something to do with the integration functions of Scipy, which I have no experience with at all.

Comment: Ah, I'm using it to pass a function as result to work with the integration functions, in particular the ```gauss``` function, that (in theory) is supposed to be a function of `x`, while already having the parameters `func` and time `t`